# How to get the second result from my SQL, and also keep the first result

Tags: php, mysql

here is my PHP code that I get the value from the question as a textbox in HTML. Now it will an answer that match with the question from the database, now when I stat typing the second question to match with the database. I want it appears on the second line, but I don't know how to do that part. it's like this webapp. http://www.simsimi.com/talk.htm

```
$question = $_POST['question'];

$sql = "select * from qa where question like '$question' order by rand() limit 1";
$dbquery = mysql_query($sql);
echo "$dbquery";

if (mysql_num_rows($dbquery)==0) {
    $error = "I don\'t know. Please teach me.";
    // echo "<script>";
    // echo "alert('I don\'t know. Please teach me.')";
    // echo "</script>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=right>$question</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=left>$error</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}else{

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($dbquery)){
    $ques = $row[1];
    $ans = $row[2];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=right>$ques</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=left>$ans</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Is it the ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

So... this is not actually mysql related, is it? If I'm getting this right, what you want is to add results to your HTML markup?

In which case I would suggest having a look at Javascript libraries.

For instance, you could check this out : http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I'm not allowed to use jQuery as this is a part of my project requested by my lecturer. Thanks